# The callback of the blur listener doesn't recognize a state value

Tags: javascript, callback, setinterval

In my react native component I have two buttons

```
            <Button
                title='Start moving'
                onPress={() => {
                    setIntervalId(startMoving(addLocation))
                }}
            />
            <Button
                title='Finish moving'
                onPress={() => {
                    stopMoving(intervalId);
            />
```

Where startMoving and stopMoving are

```
export const startMoving = () => {
    var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        //… Do something
    }, 1000);
    return intervalId;
};

export const stopMoving = (intervalId) => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
};
```

As you can see, startMoving returns the intervalId returned by setInterval, and It saves it in a state

```
    const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(0)
```

When I press the button Finish moving, it calls stopMoving with the value of intervalId. Here, it works perfectly fine

But I want to stop the moving when the user navigates away to another component also, then, I declared the event blur:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const blurOff = navigation.addListener('blur', stopMovingId);
        return () => {
            blurOff;
        };
    }, [navigation]);
```

Where stopMovingId basically calls stopMoving with the value of intervalId

```
    const stopMovingId = () => {
        stopMoving(intervalId)
    }
```

(I didn’t know how to set navigation.addListener('blur', stopMoving… where stopMoving should be called with the argument intervalId)

The problem is that when the **blur** event executes stopMovingId() the value it sends as *intervalId* is 0, and not the value of the state *intervalId*

Rafael

Comment: Do you by chance have `stopMovingId` defined inside of a hook?

Comment: No, it's inside the component but not in a hook

Comment: The `useEffect` is called before any press of a button. It is called once `navigation` exists, probably when the component mounts with the default state of `0` that has been assigned. Also, what is `stopMovingId`, it is not declared anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think this is a scope issue. When the `useEffect` is called, it sets the handler to be `stopMovingId` which has a reference to `intervalId` but the reference to that function and subsequently that state value are not updated on state changes.

Please try the following:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const blurOff = navigation.addListener('blur', () => stopMoving(intervalId));
        return () => {
            blurOff();
        };
    }, [navigation, intervalId]);
```